# Adding pointers to an array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to make a program that for a given `int value` keeps the amount of dividers:
`int amount_of_dividers` and a list of those dividers: `int* dividers`

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int value;
    int amount;
    int* dividers;
} Divide;

int main(){
Divide ** tt;
read_dividers(tt,5);
}


/* the functions "amount_of_dividers(int g)" and "dividers_of(int g, int amount)" 
used in void read_divider are working properly, they are not needed for this question */

void read_divider(Divide *g){
    scanf("%d",&(g->value));
    g->amount = amount_of_dividers(g->value); 
    g->dividers = dividers_of(g->value,g->amount);
}


/* assuming that read_divider works, what causes read_dividerS to crash? */

void read_dividers(Divide ** t, int amount){
    int i = 0;
    t = malloc(amount*sizeof(Divide*)); 

    for(i = 0;i<amount;i++){
        read_divider(t[i]);
    }
}
```

Read_dividers uses an array of pointers `**t` where i'm trying to fill each element of this array with a pointer to a `Divide g` variable.

EDIT: input in this case in main() : "read_dividers(tt,5)" means the user gives 5 `int`'s, which get converted to 5 `Divide` structs.
What happens instead is the program crashes after I give in the second `int`

If any more information is missing, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: what is exactly your question... Something not working ?

Comment: Please provide the input that you're providing and the output that you're receiving vs. what you're expecting to receive as output.

Comment: @Varun See the "EDIT" below the code, I'm new to this site; kind of struggling with how much information i need to give while also making the question short as possible.

Comment: Where does it crash?  Have run it under a debugger?  Does the program just evaporate or report some kind of error?  Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `for(i = 0;i<amount;i++){` Can any number be divided by zero?

Comment: This code won't even compile.  Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: BTW: the variable `tt` is being used without being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an uninitialized `t[i]` to `read_divider`. `t` is supposed to be pointer to pointer to Divide, not pointer to Divide, you may have just got lucky on your first pass, but I suspect it failed on the very first call.